# use class to handle mutiple nested movieclips and their specific events

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a menu with five buttons. Menu is visible all the time. there is click event for each menu item. which slides corresponding movie clip from left to right. each movie clip has different nature events and respective animation and activity. for example tab 1 brings the video page. and within that movie clip I have video events like play pause volume and on complete etc. events and code. tab 2 has button group for Time and another button group Features. depending on user selection code will calculate and show value on a animated counter. tab 3 has button group for Time and button group Source. as per the user selection it will calculate and show the values as animated graph. and so on.

Right now I have all the individual tab movie clip has its own time line code for its own events. and some crossover variables and references with other tabs. Everything is working as expected. No problem. I know time line code is not the best way to do any complex project.

So, I would like to get the entire coding as one class or more classes if that is the correct way.
I am beginner as far as class logic. I have already created Main as document class and could control the general navigation of tabs and their initial look. But stuck at tab specific button events and other such unique events for the specific tab.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
any similar example or suggestions.

First of all, thanks a lot for a prompt response. It seems like I am not even a beginner. I need to read a lot and probalbly grasp all fundamental concepts thoroughly. I have gone through both the links suggested in your comments. I am trying to digest the stuff slowly. I do not have any formal informal education regarding OOP or any sort of programming. To be honest, I have hard time understanding the code you have suggeted. Not because of your code but because of my level of caliber. I will have to spend some time to make myself clearer regarding events and sequence etc. different tab contents are as movieclips to main timeline and already placed on stage. It comes and goes to its corresponding tab button click event. I am not marking your answer as yes because I still need to my own homework based on your suggestion. Thanks a lot once again. I am sure I will ask few more questions later.

Comment: You're better off starting from nothing with good resources. IMO, a lot of people learn the wrong stuff early on and never recover.

Comment: You are right. Would you recommened some online blog or website or tutorials please? Thanks

Comment: Some of the older stuff at [as3dp.com](http://www.as3dp.com/) is pretty good. However, they subscribe to the "timeline==bad" idea that I think is completely wrongheaded. Unfortunately, all the resources that disagree with that viewpoint are me :). [Here's some more](http://www.meetup.com/atlflex/files/) specifically on that topic, and [this is my blog](http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would design it:

I'd have a Menu Class, which *only* contains the buttons and "converts" clicks on them into more specific events.  That might look something like this:

```
public Class Menu extends Sprite {
     protected var buttons:Vector. = new Vector.();
     public function Menu() {
         super();
         var loops:int = numChildren;
         for (var i:int=0; i<loops; i++) {
            var button:SimpleButton = getChildAt(i) as SimpleButton;
            if (button) {
                buttons[buttons.length] = button;
                button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, broadcastMenuEvent);
            }
         }
     }
     public function broadcastMenuEvent(e:Event):void {
         var button:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
         dispatchEvent(new Event(button.name, true));//bubbling, can catch at any level
     }
}
```

The way this is built, you can change the events that are being dispatched simply by changing the name you give the instance of the button on stage. Note that you need to apply Menu as the Base Class and not the Class for this to work if you have "declare instances automatically" unchecked, because doing it that way allows the compiler to generate those instance names for you in a way your base Class doesn't have to know about.

At this point, you can then deal with those events in another place--whether it's your main document Class or whether you have a separate Controller.

I would define each of the Views you described as a separate Class as well. If you have objects coming and going on the stage, you can use one of the techniques [described here](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html) to handle that. Otherwise, it's fairly straightforward to address your timeline instances from the base Class instead of timeline code.  Again, you can listen for those events in the main document Class or a dedicated Controller--the main point is to make sure your Views are not making any important decisions and usually they should not be editing data.

You can choose to have your Main Document orchestrate how the tabs get added and removed (I'm a big fan of using the timeline with goToAndStop, but not everyone shares this preference), or, again, you can separate this logic out to a dedicated Controller. I would suggest that if it's possible to generalize how your Views work to have them implement a single [Interface](http://www.developria.com/2009/10/interfaces-and-dynamic-class-i.html). That way, you can give them a single instance name and manage them all with the same getter/setter pair (assuming you go the timeline route).

Note the Flash compiler isn't terribly sophisticated in this regard, so if you do this and your Views extend different parent Classes, you'll get compiler warnings. Just ignore these--they don't mean anything.

The thing you shoud try to root out of your code completely is the part where Views are referencing each other. The only time it's acceptable for one View to know about another is when it's a parent knowing about its child. Even then, try to have as little specific knowledge as possible. Notice in the Menu View I wrote as an example, the parent only knows there *may* be some SimpleButtons, but it has no specific knowledge of where they are on stage, what, specifically, is in them, or even what there instance names are.

Instead of having your Views know about one another, have a third party (which, again, you can choose to use the main Document Class for or not) that transfers requests for state changes (in the form of events) from one to another.